# "Reduce" last dimension of numpy ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Given an n-dimensional numpy ndarray, what is the most efficient way to "reduce" the last dimension by one? I'm not sure about terminology here, by "reducing" I mean that e.g. given a 3D ndarray with dimensions (d1, d2, d3) I would like to obtain an ndarray with dimensions (d1, d2, d3-1) such that all affected d3-tuples are replaced by 'd3-1'-tuples consisting of their first d3-1 elements.

Comment: You mean like, `reduced_array = array[:, :, :-1]`?

Comment: Can you show a simple (e.g., small 2D or 3D ndarray) example?

Comment: Do you want to lose array elements, or are they compacted into another part of the array?

Comment: I suppose the question might not be very clear but jdehesa's answer is what I was looking for.